# How to specify degree argument in ns() in R, for constructing natural spline of degree 5?

Tags: r, regression, spline

```
 library(ISLR) 
 fit=lm(wage~bs(age ,knots =c(25 ,40 ,60),degree = 5,),data=Wage)
 fit=lm(wage~ns(age ,knots =c(25 ,40 ,60),degree = 5,),data=Wage)
```

I am able to build a regression spline of degree 5 polynomial, but how do I build a natural spline of degree 5, as the `ns()` function lacks a degree argument.

I am only able to produce a cubic natural spline using `ns()`.
Are there any other functions that could be used to produce let's say quadratic natural splines, etc?

Answer (score 2):

`ns` explicitly constructs a natural cubic spline. You can't customize the polynomial degree. To understand why, you need some basic knowledge on splines.

---

Generally for a spline of degree `d` with `k` knots (including `k - 2` interior knots and `2` boundary knots, there are

- `(d + 1)(k - 1)` piecewise polynomial coefficients
- `d(k - 2)` continuity constraints for those coefficients

hence there will be `(d + 1)(k - 1) - d(k - 2) = k + d - 1` unconstrained coefficients. This means that

- for a linear spline with `d = 1`, `k` knots give exactly `k` free coefficients;
- for a quadratic spline with `d = 2`, `k` knots give exactly `k + 1` free coefficients;
- for a cubic spline with `d = 3`, `k` knots give exactly `k + 2` free coefficients.

These are standard splines that you can get from the constructor `bs`.

---

"Natural" means extra boundary conditions so that `k` knots give `k` free coefficients. Obviously the linear spline is readily "natural"; the quadratic spline needs one more constraint; the cubic spline needs two more constraints.

It is meaningful to set natural conditions for a cubic spline: the 2nd derivative at each of the 2 boundary knots is 0. However, it is not obvious what condition(s) you need for other degree of splines. Therefore, `ns` only allows you to construct a cubic spline.

---

Note that `bs` and `ns` expect you to provide interior knots only via argument `knots`.